# Problems rendering with EEVEE

Tags: rendering

I have been rendering for a while but since Saturday and in two different projects I couldn't render with EEVEE, here is a picture of the final wrong render, render settings are well setup by default but I still have the problem and every time I render it it comes out different, sometimes all white, or all black or like these two, the second image is better but still it's not right. is it a graphic card issue not related with Blender?
after ten or twelve hours trying to render one of the projects actually rendered correctly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this the render in the preview or the exported file? maybe try to save to a different file format?

Comment: this is the exported file, I have tried with a different format, different sizes, I closed it a few times, I restarted my computer... but it still happens

Comment: have you tried rendering with Cycles? it might be a problem with your hardware